# Would society of immortals create any kind of religion?

Tags: society, religion, immortality, gods

As far as I know, the core of most religions on the Earth is an explanation of what happens to our souls/consciousness after we die and things that occur in our lives and we cannot explain scientifically.

Now let's imagine a society of truly immortal creatures - even more immortal than Tolkien's elves (who can die in combat or by sickness). These creatures cannot be physically destroyed because of their great self-regenaration ability and they simply never die of age. They don't reproduce - there is a constant-size population since the moment the population was created. Yes, they know they were created, but they have no reason to think their Creator was some kind of almighty God, because they know everything about him and they know the exact technological procedure how it happened. The only reason they don't produce new individuals by themselves is the lack of essential resources. Their science is on high level - they don't encounter any "miracles" like thunders, meteorites or earthquakes they would have to explain by the divine presence.

Would such a society ever create any kind of religion or rites? Why?

Comment: Too broad and probably also contains a biased viewpoint about the role of religions in the society. Belief in the existence of God continues to be a matter of subjectivity.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but would they even think of a god as a possibility?

Comment: Close-voters: Please don't vote to close without leaving commentary. vojta: Welcome to the site. I believe the issue being identified here is that the species/society you have created is yours, so you can decide how it evolves. Note also that there are groups of people on Earth who believe in one or more deities and groups that reject all deities.

Comment: If you ask the same question to a person on Earth (Do you believe God -or gods- exists?) the answer would depend on the religious perspective of the person. Would ***they*** think of God depends solely on whom you are asking that question. Hence, primarily opinion based.

Comment: @YoustayIgo I am not asking if all of them would be religious... I am asking if any of them would be religious.

Comment: Frostfyre has provided with the best solution for your scenario. Since it is **your** world, so if or not some (or all) of them believe in God (or gods) is your own matter of choice. A purely rational, logical and unanimously agreed answer of this question is impossible. If we take your assumption (which I don't agree with) that religions begin only as a means to explain the inexplicable phenomena in the environment and provided that ***they*** have no unanswered questions about their environments, then no, they would not believe in any God. But if this assumption about religion is wrong ...

Comment: "Why are we here?" and "where we came from?" is one of the things that pushed people to devise a god that creates, that could be enough to pull a religion overtime. And since noone pointed this out: religion is also one of the earliest ways to regulate living in a society, much easier for someone to be kept in line for fear of a god than fear of the rest of the community, from there things can evolve and mix up to become a real religion.

Comment: That is actually incorrect. With uncivilized people, you are better off wielding a knife in one hand and a spear in the other, instead of trying to scare them off of an imaginary set of gods. The role of religion and God becomes more prominent **after** the people get to some civilized status, not before it.

Comment: Your problem is your definition of religion, in the first paragraph. Check the old closed question on creating realistic religions {it'd be nice if someone would put the link here -- I've only got a bad phone to work on at the moment}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is broad, but I find 'religion' tags interesting and WB a great, mature  place to speculate.*

I suspect they would deify what is important to them.  Many religions have nothing to do with afterlife.  Ghenghis Khan believed in [Tengrism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengrism), which had little to do with 'afterlife,' so much as living in harmony with the surrounding world.  In a culture where horses, camels, or agriculture is important, there is emphasis on the Horse God, the Nomad God, or the Gods of weather.

**There exists precedents, so it is very viable: many cultures (the age-old Arabic Suffi belief in immortal Djinn, etc), to believe in the world around us without an afterlife.**  It should be no problem for your story.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's possible. Here are seven reasons people have religions.

1. Superstition has been observed in several species of animals, such as pigeons and of course humans. Superstition is difficult to distinguish from religious behavior, i.e. leaving the room to make a team score, and talking in a quiet voice to yourself to make a team score. This is one possibility, that over time, when things like that happen, a population starts to believe something is making them happen.
2. Anthropomorphism, giving human like characteristics to non living things, which is like talking to the clouds to make rain. This seems unlikely to me.
3. The belief that everything has a purpose. This seems possible, if something bad happens somehow to your species.
4. Belief in Justice, that people that do things wrong will eventually get punished by the universe or a god, this is possible as well for your species.
5. Hope of an afterlife. This doesn't apply to your species, as they don't die.
6. Hallucinogenic plants. If one of you species eats something that causes them to hallucinate, they might convince others of the existence a god.
7. Religion brings people together. If lots of people in one area can believe the same religion, it can help them live peacefully together. If a smart individual of your species could get a lot of people to believe in one religion, he could prevent wars.
   Hope that helped!
   Sources: [this article](http://listverse.com/2013/06/13/8-reasons-people-embrace-religion/)

Comment: The article cited appears to be a popular journalist's description of vague popular theories. It has no scientific merit.